# Half filled square symbol not in amssymb

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, amssymb

The question title says pretty all. I need a half-filled square symbol which can't be found in the amssymb package: something between `\blacksquare` and `\square`.

[image]

I've tried to read the source files at http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/amsfonts/source/amssymb.dtx, but it seems that I will have to use the TikZ/PGF anyway. How to proceed?

[edit] The minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
% \usepackage{stix} % uncomment this line
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Symbols used here include $\blacksquare$ and $\square$.
\end{document}
```

shows that stix changes font used in whole document. Including stix before Alegreya changes appearance of \square, which is not desired.

Comment: Hi, Have you seen at the link http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf? There is `\squarellblack` or `\squarelrblack` with `stix`package Geometric Shapes.

Comment: @Sebastiano, the Stix package offers \squarelrblack which is exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, it breaks compatibility with other packages in my preamble, for example Alegreya.

Comment: Could you kindly add your complete code, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano the MWE has been added.

Comment: Santiago thanks a lot lot for your collaboration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    Symbols used here include $\blacksquare$ and $\square$
    and $\squarelrblack$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

or load stix as `\usepackage[notextcomp]{stix}` if you want it after `amssymb`. It is also possible to use only the `\squarelrblack` from `stix`, but then the symbol is bigger than the ones from `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows3}{LS2}{stixtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\squarelrblack}{\mathord}{arrows3}{"89}
\makeatother
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    Symbols used here include $\blacksquare$ and $\square$
    and $\squarelrblack$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stix before Alegreya changes appearance of \square and \blacksquare.

Comment: Herbert I was doing the same thing myself.  I vote +1 for your answer. :-)

Comment: @Santiago: sure, they are from stix, too. I f you do not like it, the write your own command `\SquarelrBlack`